# confused by ruby/rake filelist

Tags: ruby, file, rake

Here is my code to generate a list of files

```
  files = FileList.new('c:/temp/**/*') do |fl|
    fl.exclude("*.dll")    
  end
  puts files
```

How come output still contains  *.dll file?  Something am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the glob pattern passed to `fl.exclude` is expanded against the actual file system just like the `/temp` glob pattern, but it can't do the same match because it isn't a full path.

```
fl.exclude 'c:/temp/**/*.dll'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Following DigitalRoss's answer] Or you can you a regular expresion as the pattern, see the [docs](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html). So this should work

```
files = FileList.new('c:/temp/**/*') do |fl|
  fl.exclude(/\.dll$/)
end

puts files
```